# c++ rapidjson return value

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I'm using rapidjson in my project.
I have a method which parses a json and returns part of it.

```
static rapidjson::Document getStructureInfo(std::string structureType)
{
    rapidjson::Document d = getStructuresInfo();

    rapidjson::Document out;
    out.CopyFrom(d[structureType.c_str()], d.GetAllocator());
    std::string title1 = out["title"].GetString();

    return out;
}
```

and then, I'm using that part to get a value from it.

```
rapidjson::Document info = StructureManager::getStructureInfo(type);
title2=info["title"].GetString();
```

The issue is that the title1 is read successfuly, but title2 faces an access violation issue on the following line in document.h:

```
bool IsString() const { return (flags_ & kStringFlag) != 0; }
```

I'm wondering what is the proper way to return part of a document. (I don't want to use pointers).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To returns a part of document, you can just simply returns a (const) reference of `Value`.

```
static rapidjson::Value& getStructureInfo(std::string structureType)
{
    return d[structureType.c_str()];
}

rapidjson::Value& info = StructureManager::getStructureInfo(type);
title2=info["title"].GetString();
```

By the way, the problem in your original code is due to `d.GetAllocator()` belongs to local variable `d`, the allocations will become invalid when the local variable is destructed. The following should fix it, but I recommend the above solution which uses reference to prevent copying at all.

```
out.CopyFrom(d[structureType.c_str()], out.GetAllocator());
```

Comment: Thanks, the out.GetAllocator() did the trick for me. It seems I totally misunderstood that part before.