# Rapidjson returning wrong data

Tags: c++, json, c++11, rapidjson

The json I receive:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "user_id": "acv",
    "user_type": "individual",
    "email": "abc@xyz.com",
    "user_name": "xyz",
    "user_shortname": "xx",
    "broker": "zzzz",
    "exchanges": [
      "aaa",
      "cvv",
      "bbb",
      "sss",
      "MF",
      "eee"
    ],
    "products": [
      "CNC",
      "NRML",
      "MIS",
      "BO",
      "CO"
    ],
    "order_types": [
      "MARKET",
      "LIMIT",
      "SL",
      "SL-M"
    ],
    "avatar_url": "",
    "meta": {
      "demat_consent": "consent"
    }
  }
}
```

I have a function that parses received json:
`(rj` is nothing but a namespace alias declared like `using rj=rapidjson;`)

```
rj::Value& parser(...){
    rj::Document data;

    data.Parse("data received passed as const char*");

    //------can access correct email string here------
    std::string debugstr = data["data"].GetObject()["email"].GetString();


    return data["data"];

  }
```

I use it like:

```
void func1(){
    rj::Value::Object res = parser().GetObject();
 
    //-----this string for some reason is "\003"------
    std::string debugstr = res["email"].GetString();
}
```

Why is this happening? I've ran this multiple times. I'm on Linux using latest rapidjson.

Similar to the email field, I cannot access other values correctly as well. Only one (`broker`) is correct while others are either empty strings or random garbage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familar with this library but it seems likely the problem is here

```
rj::Value& parser(...){
    ...
    return data["data"];
}
```

You are returning a reference to the internals of the `data` variable. But the `data` variable is local to `parser` and will be destroyed when `parser` is exited. So you end up with a reference to an object which has been destroyed. That explains the garbage values.

Try returning a value instead

```
rj::Value parser(...){
```

(I'm assuming this is possible with the rapidjson library).

Comment: Hey john, `Value`'s copy constructor is private. Library's author recommends this method in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313527/c-rapidjson-return-value

Comment: @hmmmmmm OK, thanks for the info. Seems I correctly identified the problem but not the solution. (Library seems unnecessarily complicated if simple copies don't work).

Comment: The difference is that in the quoted answer `d` is not local, which `data` is here.

Comment: @Surt, in the quoted question, OP has d as local member. Besides, in my code, subscript operator is supposed to return rj:: Value which would make it temporary (right?). Unless, I'm totally wrong here. Feel free to correct me.

Comment: @hmmmmmm Since values cannot be copied (copy constructor is private) it cannot be true that subscript is returning a value, it must be returning a reference. And that reference becomes invalid when `data` is destroyed, which happens when the `parser` function is exited.

Comment: @john, aah, makes sense

Comment: @john, do you have any suggestions about how I can tackle this?

Comment: @hmmmmmm As I say I'm not an expert on this library. But it seems the design is such that a fragment of JSON cannot exist without the document is it part of. So I think you have two choices either make sure that `rj::Document data;` lives outside of the `parser` method (maybe pass it in as a reference). Or create a new document specifically to hold the value you are interested in and return the new document. Then you can use the GetAllocator trick in the linked answer `out.CopyFrom(data["data"], out.GetAllocator()); return out;` where `out` is the new document.

Answer (score 0):

The root document in rapidjson differs from other json values. The Document has the allocator. If this object is deleted then all json values connected to that document is destroyed. RapidJSON  is designed to be fast, and this is one of the trade-offs that this library has done to improve speed.

Returning a reference to variable from function where the variable is created will always generate errors.

You could return the complete document in a shared pointer `std::shared_ptr`.

Here are one tutorial for [rapidjson](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=api&link=%5B%5B%229F60D5FEDE8E41CC986C10147F0AD2F7zoom%22,%22TArticleBook1%22,7133%5D,%5B%2271C91DEE3C5A4FDC8EC1114C7C18033Bzoom%22,%22TArticleBook1%22,7133%5D%5D&rows=25&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7133) and two others.